# Foreign Key Object returning null when I call from ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got a problem on Foreign Keys.

What I want is that for every Video Model there is a Profile Model link to it

An example of that would look like this:

```
public class VideoModels
{ 
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public ProfileModels Profile { get; set; }  
}
```

While in the ProfileModels

```
public class ProfileModels
{ 
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
}
```

Which technically should not have any connection with VideoModels for the VideoModels is dependent with ProfileModels and there can be 0 to many relationship.

So after that I tested it, my VideoModels has a Profile_Id parameter which is a foreign key from ProfileModels

But after creating an object and retrieving it, it returns NULL but when I check the database there is an existing Foreign Key Id.

Please help, stuck here for hours now

Comment: Please give the code sample how you are retrieving data.

Comment: Its already answered, i forgot crucial definition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Profile` would be null here due to `LazyLoading`. This allows us to have an object with many different objects that are only loaded when needed rather than loaded when a parent object is loaded. This is especially helpful if you have something like a Comments property as part of the user. Without `LazyLoading` the comments collection would be loaded whenever you wanted to grab just the `VideoModels.ID`. A downside to `LazyLoading` is that each navigation performed requires a separate query to the data source.

**To allow for LazyLoading you need to mark related object properties as virtual.**

In addition you must supply a navigation property in your context:

```
public class Database : DbContext {
    public DbSet<VideoModels> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProfileModels> PersonDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**Or**

If you want to use your current class modeling, you can achieve this by disabling `LazyLoading`.

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I just forgot to make the foreign key propery as `virtual`.

```
public class VideoModels
{ 
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual ProfileModels Profile { get; set; }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue and was able to solve it with the virtual keyword, but I also needed to add a package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`

Then enable it from the DbContext, inside `OnConfiguring`:

```
        var connString = configuration["DbConnectionString"];
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(connString);
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) the full article on Lazy Loading